# CSS3 :not example

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have to select all the elements of html ( from * ) except the children one specific div.
how can I make use it of :not of css3 ?

```
(*) - children of (#myDiv)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that, as the selector to find any child of `#myDiv` would be

```
#myDiv > *
```

But that's not a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) that could fit in `:not()`.

Your best bet is to apply styles to `*` and override (or "revert") them in `#myDiv > *`:

```
* {
    color: red;
}

#myDiv > * {
    color: black;
}
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/bCkBp/4)

Comment: I have
 *{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0 none;
         }
And I do not want to reset the settings to one of my children of #myDiv.
please help me in this...

Comment: If you want to apply browser-default padding, margin and border to elements in `#myDiv`, that's a bit of a problem. But there's no other way around this.

Comment: Liked the fact you explained why it doesn't work with :not(), that's the one thing that makes this answer awesome.

Comment: can we use 
  * *:not( * >  div#myDiv  > *}{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 border:0 none;
 }
  I know its wrong.. any help?

Comment: @Mohammed Imran Khan: That's actually redundant because of the way `*` works.

Comment: @kuroir: Thank you - I try to explain most of my answers unless they're **really** obvious or straightforward.

Comment: @kuroir: And thanks for getting my `css-selectors` answer score to this! http://cl.ly/6UDY

Comment: @Mohammed Imran Khan: You're welcome - to mark an answer as accepted click the tick under the number at the left. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Try to avoid using too many universal selectors, as they're the slowest kind of CSS selector (even when used in conjunction with combinators, as browsers parse selectors right to left).

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
:root, :not(#myDiv) > *
```

The first part there will match the root element.  The second part will match anything with a parent as long as that parent is not `#myDiv`.

Comment: Certainly does, +1. But it seems without an explicit override for `#myDiv > *`, both of our rules may appear to not work for style properties that children inherit from parents by default, e.g. `color`. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/bCkBp/7 (it works, it's just heritability of `color` that "breaks" it)

Comment: If you set `color` on `#myDiv`, then `#myDiv > *` will inherit the text color by default unless you give `#myDiv > *` its own `color`. May or may not be what the OP wants, it's just something interesting I thought of pointing out...

Comment: L33t.  I could not had said better :)